# I have a powershell module with a function returning a hashtable, how can I change the way it is formatted in the output by default?

Tags: powershell, formatting

I have a function that returns a hashtable and each entry in hashtable has three properties - `Actual`, `Declared`, `Undeclared`. Running the function outputs the hashtable like this:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PlatformShowcase               {Declared, Actual, Undeclared}
Onboarding                     {Declared, Actual, Undeclared}
BenefitsWeb                    {Declared, Actual, Undeclared}
LearningAdmin                  {Declared, Actual, Undeclared}
TaskControl                    {Declared, Actual, Undeclared}
AdminPortal                    {Declared, Actual, Undeclared}
Learning                       {Declared, Actual, Undeclared}
```

I would like to format the value differently. Instead of the boilerplate formatter that just outputs the names of the properties, I would like it to output the value of the `Undeclared` property.

I know that I can do it explicitly like this:

```
(MyFunction).GetEnumerator() | ft -Property Name, @{ Expression = { $_.Value.Undeclared }; Name = 'Value' }
```

And if instead of returning a `HashTable` I would have returned an array of `PSCustomObject` that explicit format expression might have been simpler.

I am specifically interested in customizing auto-formatting of the result.

**EDIT 1**

I am OK to change the result to an array of `PSCustomObject` if that enables custom auto formatting.

Comment: If you continue outputting a hashtable, you'd need to update how hashtables are formatted in general, which would be problematic.  You're best off outputting a custom object with a PSTypeName, and then adjusting the formatting for that PSTypeName

Comment: Please, see EDIT 1 - I am OK to use PSCustomObjects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your hashtable by simply casting it as a `[pscustomobject]`:

```
$myobj = [pscustomobject]$thathashtable
```

Then you can get fancy with typedata

```
$TypeData = @{
    TypeName = 'My.Object'
    MemberType = 'ScriptProperty'
    MemberName = 'UpperCaseName'
    Value = {$this.Name.toUpper()}
}
Update-TypeData @TypeData
```

This and other examples at: https://powershellexplained.com/2016-10-28-powershell-everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-pscustomobject/

Comment: Please, see EDIT 1 - I am OK to use PSCustomObjects

Comment: Have a look at the link I provided - I think it has a discussion there of custom formatters

Comment: I will check it.

Comment: Excellent article. Thank you very much for the link.